# IOS Development - Open url link from webview in safari instead of current webview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i have a challenging problem here . as i load some text content into a webview using loadHTMLString . Within the content , there are website links.  Upon clicking on the website links , the content shows up in the current webview.

but client wants it to show on safari upon clicking. Any idea how to achieve this?

PS. Text content loaded into webview is dynamic as client requested that they be able to manipulate the content of the text into different format as they like.

Answer (score 1):

Set the delegate of your web view and implement [webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview).

When it’s called you can read the navigation action for a URL, open the URL in a safari view controller and call the handler with .cancel to stop the web view from navigating.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this delegate like this

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if let host = navigationAction.request.url?.host {

        if host.contains("facebook.com") {
           UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: host)!, options: [:])
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
    }

    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

It's up-to you either you want some urls to open in safari or all , change the logic accordingly.